# Struct implementing IEnumerable yields unexpected error with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, class, struct, ienumerable

I've implemented a `Maybe<T>` class which implements IEnumerable in C# inspired by Mark Seemann and it works great. I've got a suite of helper extension methods that make common operations Maybe-friendly and they all work great too. I had the idea to change `Maybe<T>` from a class to a struct to prevent it from being nullable and it seems to work great with one problem:

```
var inputs = new Maybe<string>[] { /* from somewhere */ };

// This line works with class Maybe and struct Maybe
var results1 = inputs.SelectMany(x => ParseMaybe.ToInt32(x));

// This line works with class Maybe but with struct Maybe it yields a compiler error: 
// Error CS0407 'Maybe<int> ParseMaybe.ToInt32(string)' has the wrong return type
var results2 = inputs.SelectMany(ParseMaybe.ToInt32);
```

Note: Because Maybe implements IEnumerable here, I'm using SelectMany instead of Select.

This code works with the class version but gets the compiler error as a struct. Why?

Comment: Would you like to show us the `struct` and `class` implementation?

Comment: `SelectMany` is used to flatten nested collections. You should use `Select` here, otherwise you will get an enumeration of chars.

Comment: Youre right about the chars. In simplifying my example I lost some context. I fixed it to make it more clear.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/darkmyst/ecbc00e2f2f6c5f42ded is the class implementation. The struct version differs only in removing the default constructor and avoiding null refs on _value

Comment: @Charles struct are not a non nullable version of class.
They are passed as value and not as reference and are boxed-unboxed when used.
That can cause strange issue when use in foreach or during enumeration, i suggest you to avoid your idea to use it as non nullable version of class.

If non nullable values is a must for you, try to create a static helper methd dat initialize properties (or field) of its target.

Comment: Is this a "Maybe" monad? Like `Nullable<T>`, but for all types?

Comment: Yes. http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/02/04/TheBCLalreadyhasaMaybemonad/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because struct type parameters are invariant. Even though `Func<A, B>` is covariant in its return type this only applies if `B` is a reference type. This means you cannot assign a `Func<string, Maybe<int>>` to a `Func<string, IEnumerable<int>>` even though `Maybe<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` e.g.

```
Func<string, Maybe<int>> f = ParseMaybe.ToInt32;
Func<string, IEnumerable<int>> g = f; //won't compile
```

In contrast the following will compile since `int[]` is a reference type:

```
Func<string, int[]> f = ???
Func<string, IEnumerable<int>> g = f;
```